# Return object from a method c++

Tags: c++, reference, local-variables

I created this class in my program

Node.h

```
class Node {
private:
    std::string id;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
public:
    Node();
    Node(const Node& orig);
    Node(std::string id, double lat, double lon);
    virtual ~Node();

    void SetLongitude(double longitude);
    double const & GetLongitude() const;

    void SetLatitude(double latitude);
    double const & GetLatitude() const;

    void SetId(std::string id);
    std::string const & GetId() const;
};
```

Node.cpp

```
    Node::Node() {
}

Node::Node(const Node& orig) {

    this->id = orig.id;
    this->latitude = orig.latitude;
    this->longitude = orig.longitude;
}

Node::~Node() {
}

Node::Node(std::string id, double lat, double lon){
    this->id = id;
    this->latitude = lat;
    this->longitude = lon;
}

void Node::SetLongitude(double longitude) {
    this->longitude = longitude;
}

double const & Node::GetLongitude() const {
    return longitude;
}

void Node::SetLatitude(double latitude) {
    this->latitude = latitude;
}

double const & Node::GetLatitude() const {
    return latitude;
}

void Node::SetId(std::string id) {
    this->id = id;
}

std::string const & Node::GetId() const {
    return id;
}
```

I created a method that returning a node

```
Node& GeomertyHelper::GetPerpendicularPoint(double pointLat, double pointLon, Node front, Node back) const
{
    Node node;
    node.SetLatitude(x4);
    node.SetLongitude(y4);

    return node;
}
```

then I'm getting the values from this method.

```
Node projectionPoint = GeomertyHelper::Instance().GetPerpendicularPoint(lat, lon,
                Node("",nearestNode.GetLatitude(), nearestNode.GetLongitude()),
                Node("",frontNodeLat, frontNodeLon));

double frontNodeLat1 = projectionPoint.GetLatitude();
double frontNodeLon1 = projectionPoint.GetLongitude();

std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(7) << "DIS= Lat------->>>>>" << frontNodeLat1;
std::cout << std::setprecision(7) << "DIS= Lon------->>>>>" << frontNodeLon1 << std::endl;
```

But I'm getting 0s for the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are returning a reference to a temporary object in `GeomertyHelper::GetPerpendicularPoint`. You should let the method return a `Node` instead of a `Node&` since the current method results in undefined behaviour.

Edit: Allocating and returning a `Node*` would work, too. But this shouldn't be necessary since the `Node` object likely wouldn't be copied when returning it due to Return Value Optimization anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a reference to a local object. That is very bad!!!
The object will be destroyed when the function exits and you end up with a piece of memory which is not yours.

```
Node& GeomertyHelper::GetPerpendicularPoint
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing this:

```
Node node;
node.SetLatitude(x4);
node.SetLongitude(y4);

return node;
```

you allocate the node on the stack, after exiting the function the stack gets freed so node becomes invalid location in the memory, and this cause undefined behaviour.

You should return something like `Node*` and allocate this using `new` so it will sit in the heap and won't be freed on function exit:

```
Node* GeomertyHelper::GetPerpendicularPoint(double pointLat, double pointLon, Node front, Node back) const
{
    Node* node = new Node();
    node.SetLatitude(x4);
    node.SetLongitude(y4);

    return node;
}
```

But here you should not forget to do `delete node` when you finished working with it, or else it will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** return a reference to an object whose ownership is *secure*. By that I mean you can return a reference if the object is guaranteed to be alive during the use of the object reference that was returned. This is the case if you were using a "manager" type object who was alive for the entire process lifetime.

The issue is that your object is temporary, and it will be deleted while you are attempting to use it. You many not notice this sometimes as the memory that is being referenced may not be cleaned up straight away. However it will happen at some point that this will cause a crash or some other weird behaviour.

As for alternatives you should not return a raw pointer IMO, because who "owns" the object in that case? The guy who created it or the guy using it? You should return a `std::unique_ptr<Node>` instead. This makes it less ambiguous that the code using the Node is the owner. It also forces the calling code to decide what it wants to do with it. It will have to be stored at a higher scope or be destroyed.

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> GeomertyHelper::GetPerpendicularPoint(double pointLat, double pointLon, Node front, Node back) const
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> node( new Node() );
    node->SetLatitude(x4);
    node->SetLongitude(y4);
    return node;
}
```

**NOTE**: Returning a pointer *is not necessary* here... my caveat above really doesn't apply where you can just return the value (which is what you should do here).

Comment: Why not return by value? It seems simpler.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yep... sorry I should specify that I meant instead of returning a raw pointer which was being advocated here (where it is not really needed). You are right though a return value is simpler.